# What is the proper way to get value from local server and display it on webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, ftp, sftp, md5sum

I'm creating an online file MD5sum calculator.

Basically, a person selects a file from the local storage, then presses a button. The file is then sent over SFTP to a local server, where a Python script calculates the MD5sum of the file.
After processing, the value (which is the MD5sum) should somehow be transferred back to the website and shown.

I am stuck on how to transfer the value from the local server to the webpage.
My temporary solution is to create a small text file with MD5sum as its contents, and transfer it back, also over SFTP. PHP then reads the contents of the file with the MD5sum value and, using JavaScript, sets an HTML element's text value to the value from the file with MD5sum.

Is there a better way to get the value from a local server to be displayed on the webpage?

Comment: What if you made a get request from the client side and returned the MD5sum after it was done processing. If it took too long, just ask again, or tell the user it failed.

Comment: Python has the ability to recieve ajax requests (I'm not that sure about sending a response back). It depends on the framework you're using.